# How do I put generated sources in private include paths in Bazel?

Tags: bazel

If I put a `genrule` output in a `cc_library`, how can I put it in a private include path?

Let's say I have a `file.c` like this:

```
#include <config.h>
```

Here is a build script that illustrates the problem:

```
genrule(
    name = "config",
    outs = ["config.h"],
    cmd = "touch $@",
)

cc_library(
    name = "lib",
    srcs = [
        ":config",
        "file.c",
    ],
    copts = [
        "-isystem",
        # <- what goes here?
    ],
)
```

I could use `includes`, but this would be inherited by other targets, which I don't want.

The actual path to the genrule output will be something like `bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/...` which changes depending on the configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can use the `$(GENDIR)` "make variable" in `copts`:

```
cc_library(
   name = "mylib",
   copts = ["-I", "$(GENDIR)/path/to/package"],
)
```

Unfortunately, one must hardcode the path to the package because the `$(RULEDIR)` variable is not currently supported there.